# Encode result type in a discriminated union

Tags: f#

I have multiple code blocks which can either end with an unrecoverable error, be cancelled by user input or otherwise provide an input value for the next code block. How then to deal with the final step, that is *Success* (all computations finished successfully).

```
type Res<'T> =
| Next of 'T
| Cancel
| Fail of string

module Res =
    let bind arg f =
        match arg with
        | Next x -> f x
        | Cancel -> Cancel
        | Fail x -> Fail x
```

I'm now able to string these steps together like this, alas, the type Res<unit> takes on a special meaning.

```
let (|?>) = Res.bind

firstFunc() 
|?> fun intermediateResult ->
    secondFunc intermediateResult
    ...
    |?> fun otherResult ->
        lastFunc otherResult
|> function
| Fail msg -> printfn "Error: %s" msg
| Cancel -> printfn "Cancelled"
| Next() -> printfn "Succeeded"
```

If I had encoded *Success* as a discrete alternative, I would be stuck with an extra case *Next _* in the final clause. What's the preferred way around this?

Comment: Would it be better to replace `Next of 'T` with `Success of 'T`? They seem to be the same thing.

Comment: @LeafGarland: I meant `Next of 'T` vs. `Success`, since I'm not expecting a meaningful value from the last function in the chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your `Next of 'T` and `Success of 'T` represent almost the same thing - they mean that a computation block finished and returned some value. For composability reasons, it should not matter if the computation block is the last one in the entire chain or if it is not - in principle, the behavior of computation block should be the same regardless of whether it is at the beginning or at the end of your pipeline.

But if you want to distinguish between the two cases (and if this does not affect the properties when composing the blocks), then I would probably have `Success` case with an additional flag:

```
type ResultKind = Success | Next
type Result<'T> =
  | Completed of 'T * ResultKind
  | Cancel
  | Fail of string
```

Now you can use `Completed(42, Success)` to create a final value (and `Completed(42, Next)` to create an immediate result).

In pattern matching, you can ignore the flag and just write `| Completed(result, _) -> ...`